# why does countdown cancel doesnt work when I cancel it

Tags: android

I am trying to make a mini game like a quiz. If you answer correctly in the specific time, your score is saved in a sqlite db (if it is higher than the highscore). Otherwise, if the time expires, it will show you a dialog and tell you the time expired. The problem is that the app crashes because the coundowntimes never closses. Somehow it runs in the background and: 
1. if I am in another activity, the app crash because the dialog is not open in the specified activity (the levelQuizOne activity)
2. If I am in the middle of the quiz, the dialog appears even if the time didnt expired yet (so I suppose it's the last countdown timer that activate the onFinish() method).

Please help if you have any idea, I am new in Android programming area. Thank you

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LevelQuizOneActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Ești sigur că vrei să renunți? Tot progresul tău se va pierde");
        builder.setPositiveButton("DA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                timeRemaining = 0;
                if(countDownTimer != null)
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(LevelQuizOneActivity.this, LevelListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NU", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Renunț");
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Here I get the questions out of the DB, start the quiz and start the countdown

```
    questionCountTotal = questionQuizOneList_levelOne.size();
                Collections.shuffle(questionQuizOneList_levelOne); //amestecam interbarile inter ele ca sa nu fie mereu aceleasi
                Collections.shuffle(answersList_levelOne);

                showNextQuestion_levelOne();

                startCountdown();

                btn_next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt_op1.setClickable(true);
                txt_op2.setClickable(true);
                txt_op3.setClickable(true);
                txt_op4.setClickable(true);
                checkAnswers_levelOne();
                btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showNextQuestion_levelOne();
                        timeRemaining = 0;
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                    }
                });

    private void showNextQuestion_levelOne() {

            timeRemaining = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS_LEVEL_ONE_QUIZ_ONE;
            startCountdown();
            updateCountdownText();

            txt_op1.setClickable(true);
            txt_op2.setClickable(true);
            txt_op3.setClickable(true);
            txt_op4.setClickable(true);
            btn_next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img_answer.setAlpha(0f);

            ArrayList<String> posibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>();

            if (questionCounter < questionCountTotal) {
                btn_next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                currentQuestion = questionQuizOneList_levelOne.get(questionCounter);

                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Answers item : answersList_levelOne) {
                    list.add(item.getText_raspuns());
                }
                list.remove(questionQuizOneList_levelOne.get(questionCounter).getCod_raspuns_corect());

                posibleAnswers.add(list.get(0));
                posibleAnswers.add(list.get(1));
                posibleAnswers.add(list.get(2));
                posibleAnswers.add(questionQuizOneList_levelOne.get(questionCounter).getCod_raspuns_corect());
                Collections.shuffle(posibleAnswers);

                if(currentQuestion.getDrawable_res().equals("o")){
                    img_quizHiragana.setImageResource(LevelQuizOneActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier
                            (currentQuestion.getDrawable_res(), "drawable", LevelQuizOneActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                } else if(currentQuestion.getDrawable_res().equals("i")){
                    img_quizHiragana.setImageResource(LevelQuizOneActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier
                            (currentQuestion.getDrawable_res(), "drawable", LevelQuizOneActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                } else
                    img_quizHiragana.setImageResource(LevelQuizOneActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier
                            (currentQuestion.getDrawable_res() + "1", "drawable", LevelQuizOneActivity.this.getPackageName()));

                txt_op1.setText(posibleAnswers.get(0));
                txt_op2.setText(posibleAnswers.get(1));
                txt_op3.setText(posibleAnswers.get(2));
                txt_op4.setText(posibleAnswers.get(3));

                questionCounter++;
                txt_questionCount.setText("Întrebare: " + questionCounter + "/" + questionCountTotal);

            } else {
                finishQuiz();
            }
        }

        private void startCountdown() {
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeRemaining, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
                    updateCountdownText();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    //COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS_LEVEL_ONE_QUIZ_ONE = 0;
                    //timeRemaining = 0;
                    //finishQuiz();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LevelQuizOneActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            timeRemaining = 0;
                            if(countDownTimer != null)
                                countDownTimer.cancel();
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(LevelQuizOneActivity.this, LevelListActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            };

            countDownTimer.start();
        }

        private void updateCountdownText(){

            int minutes = (int)(timeRemaining / 1000) / 60;
            int seconds = (int) (timeRemaining / 1000) % 60;

            String timeFormated = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

            txt_time.setText(timeFormated);

            if(timeRemaining < 10000) {
                txt_time.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            } else {
                txt_time.setTextColor(txtColor);
            }
        }

        private void finishQuiz(){
            int id;

            if(LevelListActivity.level_type.equals("level1") && GameActivity.quiz_type.equals("quiz1")) {

                int scoreDB = dbHelper.getScore(1, 1);

                if (btn_next.getText().equals("Finish")) {
                    if (score > scoreDB) {
                        id = dbHelper.getScoreID(1, 1);
                        Score s = new Score(1, 1, score);
                        dbHelper.updateScore(s, String.valueOf(id));

                    }
                }

                timeRemaining = 0;
                countDownTimer.cancel();

                Intent intent = new Intent(LevelQuizOneActivity.this, LevelListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        private void checkAnswers_levelOne() {

            txt_op1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn_next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (txt_op1.getText().toString().equals(currentQuestion.getCod_raspuns_corect())) {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);

                        score += 10;
                        txt_score.setText("Punctaj: " + score);

                    } else {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.incorrect);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
                    }

                    showSolution();
                }
            });
            txt_op2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn_next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (txt_op2.getText().toString().equals(currentQuestion.getCod_raspuns_corect())) {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
    //
                        score += 10;
                        txt_score.setText("Punctaj: " + score);

                    } else {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.incorrect);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
                    }

                    showSolution();
                }
            });
            txt_op3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn_next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (txt_op3.getText().toString().equals(currentQuestion.getCod_raspuns_corect())) {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
    //
                        score += 10;
                        txt_score.setText("Punctaj: " + score);

                    } else {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.incorrect);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
                    }

                    showSolution();
                }
            });
            txt_op4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btn_next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (txt_op4.getText().toString().equals(currentQuestion.getCod_raspuns_corect())) {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
    //
                        score += 10;
                        txt_score.setText("Punctaj: " + score);

                    } else {
                        img_answer.setImageResource(R.drawable.incorrect);
                        img_answer.setAlpha(1f);
                        txt_op1.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op2.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op3.setClickable(false);
                        txt_op4.setClickable(false);
                    }

                    showSolution();
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: You create more than one instance of a `CountDownTimer` and update the instance variable, as soon as this happens there is no way to cancel the prior reference, and will continue until it has counted down, holding a strong reference to the `Activity` or `Fragment`.  You need handle a current countime timer reference, before updating to the reference to a new instance.

Comment: @MarkKeen thank you. Yes, It is as you said. Now it's working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countDownTimer.cancel(); //first cancel the current timer
                showNextQuestion_levelOne();
                timeRemaining = 0;
            }
        });
```

it seems that showNextQuestion_levelOne() is executed before canceling current countDownTimer. so it creates two instances of countDownTimer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But it seems it dowsn't work. Now, 2 countdown are displaying. like 00:25 00:15 00:24 00:14 etc and when the first one reach 00:00 the dialog it's showed